# How to Show ListView in CardView of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I need to show `listview` inside a `cardview` of the `recyclerview` on click button! but if I write *apple* and than *pear*, I get only *pear* so I don't get `listview` with all data that I inserted. But the `arraylist` into `arrayadapter` contains all items. I don't know why `listivew` doesn't shows all items.

Someone can help me?

THANKS EVERYBODY!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAANJ.png)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->




        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/videoImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/videoNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Restaurant Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitleVideoTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Some address placeholder"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <!--  <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/shareButton2"
              android:layout_gravity="left"
              android:src="@mipmap/facebook_share"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
              android:onClick="shareTutorialonFB">

          </ImageView>
  -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Get direction: 2km away"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shareButton2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@mipmap/facebook_share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

        </ImageView>
      <!-- <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preferiti_imageview"
            android:src="@mipmap/preferiti"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@mipmap/facebook_share"

            >

        </ImageView>-->
        <ToggleButton

            android:id="@+id/preferiti"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="76dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textOff="aggiungi ai preferiti"
            android:textOn="togli dai preferiti"

            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="Multiline EditText by XML layout"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:background="#d3d7b6"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="commenta"
            />

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RECYCLERVIEW ADAPTER:

```
   public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.VideoHolder> {

        private ArrayList<Video> mData;
        private ArrayList<Video> mData2;
        private Fragment mACtivity;
        private OnImageClickListener onImageClickListener;
        String iddd;
        int id_item;
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayListInteger;
        int c;
        String d = "";
        ArrayList<String> arrayListString;
        int j;
        Context context;
        ArrayList<String>arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
        ;
        String []mDataset=new String[100];
        Context mContext;
        //private static List<String> mDataset = new ArrayList<>();



        public VideoAdapter(ArrayList<Video> data, ArrayList<Video> data2, Fragment fragment, OnImageClickListener onImageClickListener, String id, ArrayList<Integer> al,Context mContext) {
            this.mData = data;
            this.mData2 = data2;

            this.mACtivity = fragment;
            this.onImageClickListener = onImageClickListener;

            this.iddd = id;
            this.id_item = id_item;
            this.arrayListInteger = al;
            this.context=mContext;
           // arrayListInteger.clear();
            System.out.println("NO O SI?" + arrayListInteger);

            System.out.println("SI O NO?" + arrayListString);


        }




        @Override
        public VideoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.anteprima_list_item, parent, false);
            VideoHolder vh = new VideoHolder(view, new CustomEditTextListener());

            return vh;
        }

        public interface OnImageClickListener {
            void onImageClick(String imageData);

            void onImageClick2(String imageData);

            void onPreferitiClick2(String imageData, String titolo, String sottotitolo, String data, String id);

            void onTogliPreferitiClick2(String imageData, String id);
            //void aggiungiCommento(String imageData, String id);



        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoHolder holder, final int position) {

            final Video video = mData.get(position);
            final Video video2 = mData2.get(position);
            final int pos=position;
            holder.customEditTextListener.setPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            holder.tw.setText(mDataset[holder.getAdapterPosition()]);
            holder.button.setTag(position);
            holder.tw.setTag(position);
           // holder.tw.setText(mDataset.get(position));
            holder.tw.setText(mDataset[position]);  // <-- add this line

    //        holder.lw.setTag(position);
    //        holder.tw.setText(mDataset[position]);


            // holder.setCommento(holder.tw.get(position));

            holder.setTitolo(video.getTitolo());
            holder.setSottoTitolo(video.getSottotitolo());

            holder.setData(video.getData());


            System.out.println("ARRAYLISTINTEGER"+arrayListInteger.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayListInteger.size(); i++) {

                c = arrayListInteger.get(i);
                System.out.println("ARRAYLISTINTEGER"+c);




                if (c == position) {
                        System.out.println("POSIZIONE:" + c + "VALORE:" + d);

                        System.out.println("INDICE ARRAYLIST:" + c);

                        holder.preferiti.setText("togli dai preferiti");



                          }
            }





            Glide.with(mACtivity)
                    .load(video2.getPic())
                    .into(holder.videoImageView);

            holder.linearlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onImageClickListener.onImageClick(video2.getPic());

                }
            });
            holder.iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onImageClickListener.onImageClick2(video2.getPic());

                }
            });
               /* holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        holder.tt.setText(holder.tw.getText());
                    }
                });*/
            //arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();



            holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = (int) v.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    System.out.println("IDDD:"+iddd);
                    System.out.println("IDDD:"+video2.getPic());

                    String commento= (holder.tw.getText().toString());

                    arrayList.add(commento);


                    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

                    holder.lw.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   // Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),adapter.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    System.out.println("LISTVIEW:"+arrayList);
                    System.out.println("LISTVIEW:"+arrayList.size());
                    System.out.println("LISTVIEW:"+adapter.getCount());






                }

            });
public class VideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView videoImageView;
        TextView videoNameTextView;
        TextView subtitleVideoTextView;
        TextView dateTextView;
        LinearLayout linearlayout;
        ImageView iv;
        Button button;
        EditText tw;
        TextView tt;
        ListView lw;


        //ImageView preferiti_imageview;

        ToggleButton preferiti;


        public CustomEditTextListener customEditTextListener;

        public  VideoHolder(View itemView, CustomEditTextListener customEditTextListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.customEditTextListener = customEditTextListener;

            linearlayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById((R.id.linearlayout));

            videoImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoImageView);
            videoNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoNameTextView);
            subtitleVideoTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitleVideoTextView);
            dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
            iv=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton2);
            //preferiti_imageview=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.preferiti_imageview);
            preferiti=(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.preferiti);
            button=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            tw=(EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.et);
          //  tt=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_entry_title);
            lw=(ListView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
            this.tw.addTextChangedListener(customEditTextListener);




        }




        public void setTitolo(String titolo) {
            videoNameTextView.setText(titolo);
        }

        public void setSottoTitolo(String sottotitolo) {
            subtitleVideoTextView.setText(sottotitolo);
        }
        public void setCommento(ArrayList<String> commento) {
            tt.setText((CharSequence) commento);
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            dateTextView.setText(data);
        }


    }

private class CustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
    private int position;


    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        mDataset[position] = s.toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `Custom View` that extends from `CardView` in your case, lets say `MyCustomView`, then add what you want inside it;

```
public class MyCustomView extends CardView{
    //your layout views here

    //your list, could be recycler
    ListView listView;
    //your list adapter;
    Adapter adapter;

    public MyCustomView(Context context){this(context, null);}
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context){
         View rootView = inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view_item, this);
         //inflate and reference your views here

         //initialize list view here
         list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(r.id.custom_view_list);
         adapter = new Adapter(context);

         //set list adapter here
         list.setAdapter(adapter)        
    }

    public void updateListElements(List<Elements> elements){
        this.adapter.updateElements(elements);
    }
}
```

then you will change your `RecyclerView` to use `MyCustomView`.
Inside the `onBindViewHolder`, you can set the `ListView` elements;

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewElementViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CustomViewElement element = filteredElements.get(position);

    //set your custom view elements here,
    holder.myCustomView.updateElements(element.getItemsResumo());
}
```

In `CustomViewElementViewHolder`, there are only a layout with `MyCustomView`;

- I create a update method inside inside my adapters, you can check in this 
  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281592/display-random-page-on-recycleview/48284518#48284518).
- For more info about on how to create custom views, check [android training - custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).
- Also, there are some [guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html) about card view that you should check.

Comment: public class MyCustomView extends CardView must be a inner class of my VideoAdapter?

Comment: sorry, can you make example with my code? please...i am new to use listview into card view into recycler view

Comment: @Marcus, I recommend adding it as a external file, but both approach could work;